# Insert LaTeX code into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, latex

I am using PHP and MySql. TeX is posted to server.php file through a form and exploded into an array:

```
foreach($_POST['ques'] as $i){  
  $arr = explode('~', $i);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `QUESTIONS`(`Text`) VALUES ('$arr[2]')";

$run = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Btw echo $arr[2]; shows correct Tex syntax : "[\Rightarrow{z=\frac{43}{-44}}]"

But on database it is stored without backslashes "[Rightarrow{z=frac{43}{-44}}]"

Comment: Yeah, but what have you done so far? Show us how you execute your query

Comment: Assuming that the string is correctly formed in PHP (so you haven't, for example, written it as a PHP literal and done it wrong), the string should not change in going to and from the database. Make sure that content destined for the database is being appropriately escaped - you should be using parameterised queries.

Comment: Your question appears to be related to escaping of database query parameters. Anyway, you are writing code that is vulnerable to SQL injection. Happily, this has the same solution as your problem does, namely using a more up-to-date database library and making use of prepared statements.

Comment: thanks @Hammerite I'll try to use parameterised query for this and use new library. Any suggestions for open-source library?

Comment: PDO is the standard suggestion. It comes bundled with all recent versions of PHP and includes a driver for MySQL.

Comment: @Hacktacus See my answer: mysqli_ and PDO are included in PHP5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use old mysql_* functions. Use mysqli_*. or PDO as in this example.

The parameterized/prepared query makes you to stop worrying about quoting and malicious sql-attacks. (But drive safely anyway)

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `QUESTIONS`(`Text`) VALUES (?)");
$sth->execute(array($arr[2]));
```